# Having One Instance Of Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have a problem with Activity navigation and the back stack and I was hoping you could clear it up for me.

**The Problem**

Root Activity >>> SecondActivity >> HomeButton

This then takes me to the home page and from there I select...

Gmail >> Message >> Open attachment in my application >> ImportActivity >> RootActivity

The outcome is a new task being started and another instance of my application being used. This is unacceptable as I don't want two separate tasks running I only want one.

**The Desired Outcome**

What I want to happen is when the user opens the attachment and **ImportActivity** finishes what its doing (it has `android:noHistory` set to true)  and calls `startActivity(intent)`, `RootActivity` is started, but keeping only one instance and the rest of the activities on top of it in the original task (in this case `SecondActivity`)are removed.

The reason I want this is if the user navigates out of my application after importing the file and then touches the app icon it loads the first task with its back stack and I have two tasks running in which the user can be in two different parts of my application at once.

**What I have tried**

I have played around with the launch mode but none of them really give me the functionality that I need.

Launch Modes I have tried..

*android:launchMode="singleTask"* - this just started the root activity again each time it was launched. Even if the user pressed the home button inside my application and touched the App icon the back stack was destroyed.

*android:launchMode="singleInstance* = doesn't allow any other activites to run in the task.

Also when calling the intent to start the `RootActivity` I have used the following to no avail.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ImportActivity.this,TrackingActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Is it possible to do what I want?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Have you tried using the Single Top flag?

Comment: What about RootActivity with singleTask mode, where you save its state in onPause(). When user returns to RootActivity, a new instance is created that reads the saved state.

Comment: Use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` when you launch your TrackingActivity

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion regarding `taskAffinity`?

Answer (score 5):

You say

```
Gmail >> Message >> Open attachment in my application >> ImportActivity >> RootActivity
```

but that may not be right. In this circumstance, gmail will issue an `Intent` targeted at the `ImportActivity` in your app. `ImportActivity` will execute. However, my reading of https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html suggests that `ImportActivity` will execute as part of the same task as gmail and will be put on top of the back stack for the gmail task, unless you take special steps in the manifest to prevent that or gmail specifically invokes it as a separate task. When `ImportActivity` finishes, it shouldn't call `startActivity(intentForRootActivity)` but should just call `finish()` so that it will be destroyed and the activity from gmail which lies underneath it in the back stack will appear.

If `ImportActivity` did call `startActivity(intentForRootActivity)` then `RootActivity` would just go onto the top of the gmail task and appear on the gmail back stack. Touching `home` and then the launcher icon for gmail would see `RootActivity` reappear, hiding gmail underneath.

I think you need `android:launchMode="standard"` in the manifest declaration of `ImportActivity`.

The task which represents the older, stand-alone instance of your app will not be modified. If someone touches the launcher icon for your app, the old state of your app will be restored, unaffected by whatever happened in the gmail task.

The document http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html is rather vague about how Activities map onto processes here (causing David Wasser to comment on my earlier version of this answer) but it seems that the Activities of gmail will execute in one linux process with one linux user id and the `ImportActivity` will execute in another linux process with another user id. However, they can all form part of one task with one back stack.

`ImportActivity` will execute, as part of the gmail task, with the same effective Linux User ID as it would had it executed as part of your standalone app - and different from the Linux user ID that gmail executes with. This sounds unlikely and complicated but seems to be implied by https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html. That makes sense; if `ImportActivity` needs to get at, say, the user preferences stored for your app, it needs to read the preference file as if it were the user defined for your app, not the user defined for gmail.

I haven't tried executing any of this. If I have hold of entirely the wrong end of the stick, I'm sure someone will soon tell us!

Comment: Your statements at the beginning of this answer are wrong. You are confusing 2 completely different concepts: Android **task** is NOT an operating system **process**. The security model for Android uses unique user-IDs for each application and relies on the operating system's security mechanism. This means that your code will **never** run in the same process (memory) space as Gmail code and it will **never** have the same user-ID as Gmail (or any other application). The import activity **may** be in the same task stack as he Gmail application, this depends on how Gmail starts the activity.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that a task is not a process, and that user ids are application-specific, and that `import`'s task stack can depend on  how `gmail` sends the intent. Can you direct me to the doc that explains how Activities map onto processes? I couldn't find it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html The first paragraph states that components (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider) of an application all run together in the same process (by default). You can specify in the manifest which components run in which process if you want to.  A detailed description of the security model (which also explains a lot about components, processes, etc.) can be found here: http://source.android.com/tech/security/index.html

Comment: Yes, thanks, I hunted that down and rewrote the answer while you were typing. Components of an application all run in the same process by default - but what happens to an Activity that is part of another application which isn't running at the time? It's not explicit. However, I agree your interpretation seems much more likely than my original one. Thanks for your correction.

Comment: The first sentence is "When an application component starts and the application does not have any other components running, the Android system starts a new Linux process for the application with a single thread of execution." So this is clear. If I start one of your activities and your app isn't running, a new process gets created to host your activity.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need any special `launchMode` to do this. If your import activity launches the root activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` this should do what you want. I'm guessing you have a problem with `taskAffinity`. Try this:

In your manifest, in the  declaration for the importActivity add this:

```
android:taskAffinity=""
```

If this doesn't work, please post your manifest so we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure if I got it, but if you want to go to your "root" activity with out loosing extra application stack, it would be `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` direct on flags at your `intent`, and with no extra configs on `Manifest`... and if you need to separate the task to create a new complete new stack than you can use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` as you described.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear and I don't think you've answered it here. I want to lose my previous stack if the `ImportActivity` is called. From there I navigate to the `RootActivity` of the previous task. I don't want two separate tasks

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask" at mainfest in ImportActivity.
"The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one."

Comment: The activity I want to be at the root is `RootActivity`. I have tried `singleTask` on it, however it always seemed to create a new task instead of (like you quoted) "the system routing the intent to the existing instance"

Comment: Did you try with android:launchMode="singleInstance" on your AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yea the problem with that is then this activity will be in a task all by itself...