# If my launcher activity is singleInstance how can I make application resume from the notification bar?

Tags: android, notifications, launchmode

I have a launcher activity which I need to set launchMode to singleInstance. If I do this, resuming from notification bar doesn't work anymore, it starts my launcher activity every time. How can I make them work together?

Comment: Try with `singleTask` and see if it works like so.

Comment: I asked a similar question to yours about the android activity lifecycle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847151/having-one-instance-of-activity

Comment: It is like so. I have an application which has NFC capability. If I don't put singleInstance, when I start the application with the NFC tag and try to resume it with longpress on home button and select application it restarts the app, instead of resuming it. If I don't put anything as launchMode it resumes ok when I don't start it with NFC tag. Resumes even from notification bar. So if you know how can I make it behave the same and resume normally with home button or from notification bar, regardless if I start normally the app or by NFC tag.